# Styled-components - Over 200 classes were generated, but cant get :hover to work

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I came across the error in styled-components :

Over 200 classes were generated for component......

and did the suggested fix from console, and that did the trick, but when I have a container component "Card" that when hovered should change text color of another component "Number" (which  has that suggested fix applied, then I cant change the color (i assume because style overrides the hover change, because it works fine with opacity)

the mentioned components are in src/ProgressPieCard (first 2 components)

anyone got any got suggestions, thanks in advance :)

( sorry styling/position is a bit off )

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-burnell-hsveq?file=/src/ProgressIndicatorCardPage/ProgressPieCard/styled.ts)

```js
const Number = styled.p.attrs<ColorProps>((props) => ({
  style: {
    color: props.color,
  },
}))`
  position: absolute;
  span {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
`;

const Card = styled.div.attrs<ColorProps>((props) => ({
  style: {
    background: props.color,
  },
}))`
  position: relative;
  &:hover {
    ${Number} {
      opacity: 0.5;
      // color: red;  <-- this dont work
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Values ​​from props were pass as inline styles. They have higher priority. I suggest passing values ​​from props differently. The example below will now work as you wanted.

```
const Number = styled.p<ColorProps>`
    position: absolute;
    color: ${p => p.color};
    span {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
`;

const Card = styled.div<ColorProps>`
    position: relative;
    background: ${p => p.color};
    &:hover ${Number} {
        opacity: 0.5;
        color: red;  <-- this WILL work :)
    }
`;
```